# Difference between using the db row value directly or storing the db row value in a variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

What is the different between the 2 of the following and which is the best way.

```
echo $row['dbColumnKey'];
```

and

```
$dbColumnKey = $row['dbColumnKey'];
```

Which is preferred and best method in fast execution.

Comment: `fast execution` is not affect by either. `$dbColumnKey` is shorter to type out than `$row['dbColumnKey']` other than that it is the same (although you are duplicating resources if you dont unset the array).

Comment: Why i am asking is what if i use the $row['dbColumnKey'] in multiple times.

If i use the $row['dbColumnKey'] repeatedly more than one time in a single page? does it refer the database each time its execute.

Comment: @Aravindan No it does not refer each time to the database when you use ```$row['dbColumnKey']```.The data you have fetched from the database is stored in some sort of **array-objects** form. So each time you refer ```$row['dbColumnKey']``` it fetches the value from that **array-objects**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to access `$row[‘dbColumnKey’]` more than once, assigning `dbColumnKey` to a constant and calling with `$row[self::SOME_CONST]` is easier to refactor. As you would only need to change the constant value to access a different key.

You could also assign the value to a variable, as u demonstrated in your question, and adhere to DRY principles..

Either way, developers choice as to what’s best for your use case. Any performance advantage is negligible..